# Allow users to logon to my site with Google account, without 3d party cookies

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I've been following the really simple instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) ("Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app").

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Although it does work in Chrome 83, I get warnings in the JavaScript console about third party cookies. And indeed, when my users, some of whom have third-party cookies disabled, try the Login button, it flashes a window and nothing happens.

In the documentation under Troubleshooting, it says "If many of your users have this feature enabled  ...  another workaround is to implement server-side OAuth 2.0 flows."

OK. So what do they mean by server-side OAuth 2.0 flows?

(FWIW my app is a React single page app).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's general information at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server. Here's one way to do it:

1. Your app provides a link to your users to log in. This link goes to https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=STATE&nonce=NONCE where the capitalized words are:

   - `CLIENT_ID` - registered as part of a Google Cloud Project you own, using the Cloud Console (currently under APIs & Services/OAuth Consent Screen)
   - `REDIRECT_URI` - a URI in your application that must be registered in that project
   - `STATE` - I use this to hold the eventual URI I want my user to be sent to
   - `NONCE` - to prevent replay attacks
2. When the user navigates to that URI, they are taken through a Google signin process. On successful signing, they are redirected to `REDIRECT_URI?state=STATE&code=CODE`. `STATE` is the `STATE` you provided in the earlier link, `CODE` is an authentication code.
3. Your app processes the request to that `REDIRECT_URI` by making a server-side POST request to the Google OAuth token service at https://oath2.googleapis.com/token, passing the `CODE`, `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET` (provided in the Cloud Console when registering the application), `REDIRECT_URI`, and `GRANT_TYPE` (the string `authorization_code`).

   The JSON response to that request will include a field called `id_token`. That `id_token` is a JWT that includes, among other things, the user's verified email address in the `sub` field.

   You can then establish your own session with that user information, and set a first party cookie for it. You can verify and parse that JWT with a Google auth library or a third party library.
4. Respond to the `REDIRECT_URI` with a redirect response that sets your session cookie, sending the user to the appropriate part of your app.

This is pretty verbose, but I did the above in a sample application I created and it worked for that. I hope it can be adapted to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. It took almost a day to get it working, and I still have to figure out a couple of important things like logging out, and re-logging-on-in-an-invisible-iframe-after the token expires, but this is definitely the right approach to take to oauth2 with google.

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you! I searched for details in Google's documentation and I found the following link:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect . The section about 'Server flow' allows what you want - the user authentication without third party cookies. I built a small app that uses authentication using Google endpoints and no third party cookis, and it works fine. Hope it helps.